# Webflux R2dbc problem one-to-one relation tables

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux, r2dbc

**Hi everyone I am write Rest api project with R2dbc (non-blocking) but problem is table relation**

**Task model**

```
 @Getter
 @Setter
 @Entity(name = "task")
 @Table(name = "task")
 public class Task {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id",unique = true,nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "comment_count")
    private Integer comment_count;

    @Column(name = "completed")
    private Boolean completed;

    @Column(name = "content")
    private String  content;

    @Column(name = "url")
    private String  url;

    @Column(name = "orderdata")
    private Integer orderdata;

    @Column(name = "priority")
    private Integer priority;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "due_id")//this is relation table Due but this relation retunr response null
    private Due due;

 }
```

**Due model**

```
  @Getter
  @Setter//Lombok library
  @Entity
  @Table(name = "due")
  public class Due {

    @Id
    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true, updatable = false)
    private Integer id;

   @Column(name = "date_data")
   private Date date_Data;

   @Column
   private Boolean recurring;

   @Column(name = "string_data")
  private String string_data;


}
```

**Tasks Repository**//this reactive crud repositroy

```
     @Repository
     public interface TasksRepository extends ReactiveCrudRepository<Task,Integer> {

      }
```

**Task Manager**//this is business layer

```
   @Component
   @Slf4j
   @RequiredArgsConstructor
   public class  TaskManager {

          private final TasksRepository tasksRepository;

          public Flux<Task> findAll() {
           return tasksRepository.findAll();
          }

      }
```

**Task Service**//this is service layer

```
    @Service
    @RequiredArgsConstructor
    public class TasksService {


        private final TaskManager taskManager;


          public Flux<Task> getAll() {
            return taskManager.findAll();
      }
    }
```

**Task Controller**

```
  @RestController
  @RequestMapping("/api/tasks")
  @RequiredArgsConstructor
  public class TasksController {


        private final TasksService tasksService;

         @GetMapping
         public Flux<Task> getAllTasks(){
          return tasksService.getAll();
       }
     }
```

Task Response

My Rest Api Response Task

```
     {
        "id": 1,
        "comment_count": 10,
        "completed": false,
        "content": "new content",
        "url": "http:8085.com",
        "orderdata": 5,
        "priority": 5,
        "due": {
             "id": 3,
             "date_Data": null,
             "recurring": null,
             "string_data": null
 
      }
```

**Problem One to One Relation Reponse null What is the problem ???  Please help me Thanks**

Error Trace

```
  2021-03-20 20:49:57.161 ERROR 13652 --- [actor-tcp-nio-1] 
   r.n.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler     : [id: 0x1126662b, 
    L:/127.0.0.1:55827 - R:localhost/127.0.0.1:5432] Error was received while 
     reading the incoming data. The connection will be closed.

    java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
      at  io.netty.util.internal.ReferenceCountUpdater
     .isLiveNonVolatile(ReferenceCountUpdt 
     er.java:88) ~[netty-common-4.1.59.Final.jar:4.1.59.Final]
         at 
      io.netty.buffer.AbstractReferenceCountedByteBuf
      .isAccessible(AbstractReferenceCountedByteBuf.java:56) ~[netty-buffer- 
       4.1.59.Final.jar:4.1.59.Final]
       at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.ensureAccessible(AbstractByteBuf.java:1455) ~[netty-buffer-4.1.59.Final.jar:4.1.59.Final]
at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.checkIndex(AbstractByteBuf.java:1385) ~[netty-buffer-4.1.59.Final.jar:4.1.59.Final]
at io.netty.buffer.UnsafeByteBufUtil.getBytes(UnsafeByteBufUtil.java:481) ~[netty-buffer-4.1.59.Final.jar:4.1.59.Final]
at io.netty.buffer.PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.getBytes(PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.java:130) ~[netty-buffer-4.1.59.Final.jar:4.1.59.Final]
at io.netty.buffer.PooledSlicedByteBuf.getBytes(PooledSlicedByteBuf.java:235) ~[netty-buffer-4.1.59.Final.jar:4.1.59.Final]
at io.netty.buffer.ByteBufUtil.decodeString(ByteBufUtil.java:1147) ~[netty-buffer-4.1.59.Final.jar:4.1.59.Final]
at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.toString(AbstractByteBuf.java:1248) ~[netty-buffer-4.1.59.Final.jar:4.1.59.Final]
at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.getCharSequence(AbstractByteBuf.java:515) ~[netty-buffer-4.1.59.Final.jar:4.1.59.Final]
at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.readCharSequence(AbstractByteBuf.java:520) ~[netty-buffer-4.1.59.Final.jar:4.1.59.Final]
at io.r2dbc.postgresql.util.ByteBufUtils.decode(ByteBufUtils.java:42) ~[r2dbc-postgresql-0.8.6.RELEASE.jar:0.8.6.RELEASE]
at io.r2dbc.postgresql.codec.AbstractNumericCodec.decodeNumber(AbstractNumericCodec.java:122) ~[r2dbc-postgresql-0.8.6.RELEASE.jar:0.8.6.RELEASE]
at io.r2dbc.postgresql.codec.AbstractNumericCodec.decodeNumber(AbstractNumericCodec.java:89) ~[r2dbc-postgresql-0.8.6.RELEASE.jar:0.8.6.RELEASE]
at io.r2dbc.postgresql.codec.IntegerCodec.doDecode(IntegerCodec.java:49) ~[r2dbc-postgresql-0.8.6.RELEASE.jar:0.8.6.RELEASE]
at io.r2dbc.postgresql.codec.IntegerCodec.doDecode(IntegerCodec.java:30) ~[r2dbc-postgresql-0.8.6.RELEASE.jar:0.8.6.RELEASE]
at io.r2dbc.postgresql.codec.AbstractCodec.decode(AbstractCodec.java:82) ~[r2dbc-postgresql-0.8.6.RELEASE.jar:0.8.6.RELEASE]
at io.r2dbc.postgresql.codec.DefaultCodecs.decode(DefaultCodecs.java:149) ~[r2dbc-postgresql-0.8.6.RELEASE.jar:0.8.6.RELEASE]
at io.r2dbc.postgresql.PostgresqlRow.decode(PostgresqlRow.java:90) ~[r2dbc-postgresql-0.8.6.RELEASE.jar:0.8.6.RELEASE]
at io.r2dbc.postgresql.PostgresqlRow.get(PostgresqlRow.java:77) ~[r2dbc-postgresql-0.8.6.RELEASE.jar:0.8.6.RELEASE]
at io.r2dbc.spi.Row.get(Row.java:76) ~[r2dbc-spi-0.8.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.r2dbc.convert.MappingR2dbcConverter.readFrom(MappingR2dbcConverter.java:173) ~[spring-data-r2dbc-1.2.5.jar:1.2.5]
at org.springframework.data.r2dbc.convert.MappingR2dbcConverter.readEntityFrom(MappingR2dbcConverter.java:294) ~[spring-data-r2dbc-1.2.5.jar:1.2.5]
at org.springframework.data.r2dbc.convert.MappingR2dbcConverter.readFrom(MappingR2dbcConverter.java:166) ~[spring-data-r2dbc-1.2.5.jar:1.2.5]
at org.springframework.data.r2dbc.convert.MappingR2dbcConverter.readEntityFrom(MappingR2dbcConverter.java:294) ~[spring-data-r2dbc-1.2.5.jar:1.2.5]
at org.springframework.data.r2dbc.convert.MappingR2dbcConverter.readFrom(MappingR2dbcConverter.java:166) ~[spring-data-r2dbc-1.2.5.jar:1.2.5]
at org.springframework.data.r2dbc.convert.MappingR2dbcConverter.readEntityFrom(MappingR2dbcConverter.java:294) ~[spring-data-r2dbc-1.2.5.jar:1.2.5]
at org.springframework.data.r2dbc.convert.MappingR2dbcConverter.readFrom(MappingR2dbcConverter.java:166) ~[spring-data-r2dbc-1.2.5.jar:1.2.5]
at org.springframework.data.r2dbc.convert.MappingR2dbcConverter.readEntityFrom(MappingR2dbcConverter.java:294) ~[spring-data-r2dbc-1.2.5.jar:1.2.5]
at org.springframework.data.r2dbc.convert.MappingR2dbcConverter.readFrom(MappingR2dbcConverter.java:166) ~[spring-data-r2dbc-1.2.5.jar:1.2.5]
at org.springframework.data.r2dbc.convert.MappingR2dbcConverter.readEntityFrom(MappingR2dbcConverter.java:294) ~[spring-data-r2dbc-1.2.5.jar:1.2.5]
at org.springframework.data.r2dbc.convert.MappingR2dbcConverter.readFrom(MappingR2dbcConverter.java:166) ~[spring-data-r2dbc-1.2.5.jar:1.2.5]
at org.springframework.data.r2dbc.convert.MappingR2dbcConverter.readEntityFrom(MappingR2dbcConverter.java:294) ~[spring-data-r2dbc-1.2.5.jar:1.2.5]
at org.springframework.data.r2dbc.convert.MappingR2dbcConverter.readFrom(MappingR2dbcConverter.java:166) ~[spring-data-r2dbc-1.2.5.jar:1.2.5]
at org.springframework.data.r2dbc.convert.MappingR2dbcConverter.readEntityFrom(MappingR2dbcConverter.java:294) ~[spring-data-r2dbc-1.2.5.jar:1.2.5]
at org.springframework.data.r2dbc.convert.MappingR2dbcConverter.readFrom(MappingR2dbcConverter.java:166) ~[spring-data-r2dbc-1.2.5.jar:1.2.5]
at org.springframework.data.r2dbc.convert.MappingR2dbcConverter.readEntityFrom(MappingR2dbcConverter.java:294) ~[spring-data-r2dbc-1.2.5.jar:1.2.5]
at org.springframework.data.r2dbc.convert.MappingR2dbcConverter.readFrom(MappingR2dbcConverter.java:166) ~[spring-data-r2dbc-1.2.5.jar:1.2.5]
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

R2DBC does not support relationships, so `JoinColumn` annotation won't work. Instead you can create a `DueRepository` and fetch this entity manually.

Comment: Then will it be non blocking?

Comment: So I have to use mapping when the code block is too big

Comment: It will be nonblocking if you write it properly ;) you could create a TaskDto class, which contains all fields you want to send in response, change `Due due` field in Task class to `Integer dueId` and then in `TaskManager` select and map all required data: `tasksRepository.findAll().flatMap(task -> dueRepository.findById(task.getDueId()).map(due -> new TaskDto(...)))`

Comment: Alternatively consider merging Task with Due table since its one-to-one relationship

Comment: looks interesting! Just afraid to trigger N+1 problem by inner looping dependent entities here.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this case when I was doing some queries in a service.
Taking into account that "R2DBC" does not support "JoinColumn", I did was to build a custom query in the repository.

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM task INNER JOIN due USING (id) WHERE id=:id")
Mono<NewDto> getCompleteTrx(String id);
```

But the important thing is that you have a Dto with the objects of the two tables that you are going to join, but it will not have the "table" annotations.

```
  @Getter
  @Setter
  @Entity
  public class NewDto { // depends on the relation you need

    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "comment_count")
    private Integer comment_count;

    @Column(name = "completed")
    private Boolean completed;

    @Column(name = "content")
    private String  content;

    @Column(name = "url")
    private String  url;

    @Column(name = "orderdata")
    private Integer orderdata;

    @Column(name = "priority")
    private Integer priority;

    @Column(name = "date_data")
    private Date date_Data;

    @Column(name = "string_data")
    private String string_data;
    ...
}
```

By doing this, I could solve the problem I had, because I needed to join 3 tables, and I didn't want to do 3 queries, with this only one query is needed. then you can map the DTO to the object you need from your business layer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should also limit the number of layers in the source to Controller and Service (business logic goes in here).

Answer (score -1):

Alright mate, firstly, why exactly does this "Due" entity need to be its own entity?
I mean, a task may have a deadline and it may be recurring. Keep it simple.

Regarding the code, irrespective of domain modelling aspects:

Use Long or UUID as ID field types. Personally, I've never seen int in production.

Create a CrudRepo for those "Due" entities to check out whether you can query them on their own. Write a test to verify that.

My guess is that the "JoinTable" annotation is somehow redundant and/or misconfigured. Try "Due.ID" instead of "Due_ID" to tell it which field of the Due object it should take.

Comment: I need reactive programming so I have to write with reactivecrudrepository

Comment: In the example given to me, it is given with the due one to one relationship, so it should be like that.

Comment: I think the problem is about these, but thanks for your help